# Write the above system in the matrix form $ \ x'=Ax+ f \ $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Consider the system of equations :

$ r'(t)=3r(t)+\cos t \\ \theta'(t)=r(t)-4 \theta(t)+3 \ $

Write the above system in the matrix form $ \ x'=Ax+ f \ $

**Answer:**

I am confused whether $ \ x'=Ax+f \ $ means $ x=(x,y) \ \ or \ \ x=r, \theta ) \ $.

I thought here we have to express in $ \ (x,y) \ $.

Let $ \ x=r \cos \theta, \\ y=r \sin \theta, \ $

Then,

$ x'(t)=r'(t) \cos \theta-r \sin \theta \theta'(t) \ =[3r(t)+\cos t] \cos \theta-r \sin \theta [r(t)-4 \theta (t)+3] \\ y'(t)=r'(t) \sin \theta+r \cos \theta \theta'(t)=[3r(t)+\cos t] \sin \theta+r \cos \theta [r(t)-4 \theta(t)+3] $

How to eliminate $ \ \theta \ $ and $ \ r(t) \ $ from the new system  in order to get the form $ \ x'=Ax+f \ $?

Help me doing this

Answer (score 3):

We have that

$$x=\begin{bmatrix}r(t)\\\theta(t)\end{bmatrix}$$

thus

$$ x'=Ax+ f $$

$$\begin{bmatrix}r'(t)\\\theta'(t)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3&0\\1&-4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}r(t)\\\theta(t)\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}\cos t\\3\end{bmatrix}$$